# matching values stored in variables or array with string javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im trying to find a patterns in the sentence for regex matching.. in the code below `result` contains a string and we are checking if the word `apple` is present in it.

```
    var patt = /apple/gi;
    var newResult = patt.test(result);
```

I found the above code from a used case.. But i was wondering if i have more than one values and i want to check it in the string result, lets say an array with values `var arr=["apple", "orange"]` `var patt=/arr[0]/gi`  will not work.. what could be the way in that scenario??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check multiple entries, you can use the OR operator:

```
var patt = /apple|orange/gi;
var newResult = patt.test(result);
```

if you have a variable, you can do the below, **IF**(!) your key is regexp safe of course (that is, it doesn't contains characters which have meaning in regexp syntax):

```
var key = "apple";
var patt = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
var newResult = patt.test(result);
```

Although in this case, you might as well use indexOf:

```
var key = "apple";
var newResult = result.indexOf(key) > -1;
```

Comment: no i was wondering what if the string is stored in a variable.. like var key="apple";  /key/gi will not work

Comment: ive changed the title to avoid confusion

Comment: Ah sorry, I had misunderstood the question, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

To use a string for your regex expressions, you need to create the regex using the regex  constructor.

```
var pattern = "apple|orange";
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");    // g is for global match
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions